# Vary thickness of edges based on weight in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to draw a network diagram using Python Networkx package.  I would like to vary the thickness of the edges based on the weights given to the edges.

I am using the following code which draws the diagram, but I cannot get the edge to vary its thickness based on the weight.  Can someone help me with this problem?  Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['D', 'A', 'B', 'C','A'], 'to':['A', 'D', 'A', 'E','C'], 'weight':['1', '5', '8', '3','20']})
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', edge_attr='weight', create_using=nx.DiGraph() )
nx.draw_shell(G, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color='skyblue', alpha=0.3, arrows=True, 
              weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').values())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to set the widths for each edge, i.e with an array-like of edges, you'll have to use [`nx.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges) through the width parameter, since `nx.draw` only accepts a single float. And the weights can be obtaind with [`nx.get_edge_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.get_edge_attributes.html).

Also you can draw with a shell layout using [`nx.shell_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.shell_layout.html) and using it to position the nodes instead of `nx.draw_shell`:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

widths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nodelist = G.nodes()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

pos = nx.shell_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=nodelist,
                       node_size=1500,
                       node_color='black',
                       alpha=0.7)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,
                       edgelist = widths.keys(),
                       width=list(widths.values()),
                       edge_color='lightblue',
                       alpha=0.6)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos,
                        labels=dict(zip(nodelist,nodelist)),
                        font_color='white')
plt.box(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!

What if I wanted to draw the edge labels of weights >5.  How could I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62870471/9698684 @ls2020

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for labeling the edge, not the node, but was able to figure it out.  Here it is for anyone else who might need it:

`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos, edge_labels ={(n1,n2):widths[n1,n2] for (n1,n2) in widths if widths[n1,n2] >=5}, font_colors='black')`